# Android lollipop can`t get keyboard input

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I have user keyboard input working on all android versions except on Android Lollipop (5.0).

I have used this to open software keyboard:

```
 public static void OpenKeyBoard(){     
MainActivity._Instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {         
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)    MainActivity._Instance.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(MainActivity._Instance.getWindow().getDecorView(), 0);        
    }
});
```

}

and i get user input by standard event :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
```

I have this code working for all pre Lollipop versions of Android. When I use it on Lollipop, the software keyboard appears, but when I try to click on any letter/number, the keyboard disappears and the method "onKeyDown" doesn`t receive any keycode.

Did anyone had this problem? Any opinion how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also having issues with the new Android Keyboard (Default Keyboard on lolipop), where the keyboard is dismissed as soon as the keyboard is interacted with, it seems as though it might be fireing a touch event on display objects below the keyboard.

have you had any luck on finding a fix for this issue?

Comment: Exactly. That is the problem :). I still haven't found a solution but I must solve it in the next 6-7 days because of the project I am doing, so when I find the solution i`l post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your google SDK to the latest, I did and this fixed any issues I have with the keyboard dismissing.

Comment: I have tried that, currently my Manifest looks like this:                  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="10"/>

Comment: @Rich let me know from where I will update google sdk in device

Answer (score 0):

I has this problem too. I managed to solve this by overriding the onLayout, onFocusChanged & onCheckIsTextEditor methods inside WebView. Here's the code that made it work (I generate a webview programmatically):

```
        this.webView = new WebView(context)
        {
            boolean layoutChangedOnce = false;

            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
            {
                if (!layoutChangedOnce)
                {
                    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
                    layoutChangedOnce = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
            {
                super.onFocusChanged(true, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor()
            {
                return true;
            }
        };

        this.webView.setFocusable(true);
        this.webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        addView(this.webView);
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue is not limited to just android applications but also occurs when any keyboard related event is accessed using javascript or jquery within a phone browser.

eg. I have my website which asks a user to enter zip code(numeric characters) on a certain page. Now the problem is when up tap on the input box, the numeric keyboard appears but it allows you to paste alpha-numeric characters in it as well.

Reason searched so far,
Try accessing [this](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html) through your desktop and also a mobile device running android OS 5.0+ and try different possible keystrokes.

Note:

1. When you enter any alpha-characters using mobile device with above
   mentioned configuration it shows up '229' as the keycode.
2. When you enter any alpha-characters using a desktop it shows up the
   appropriate keycode.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me I have a SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback with a thread to do drawing

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        mouse.useEvent(event);
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorinfo) {

    BaseInputConnection bic = new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
    editorinfo.actionLabel = null;
    editorinfo.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL;
    editorinfo.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN;
    bic.finishComposingText();
    return bic;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{

    input.useEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using AlertDialog editText programmatically. Eg:

```
public void KeyboardTextField(int id){              
    if (id == 0){
        final String title = getStringResourceByName("profile_title");       
        final String createP = getStringResourceByName("profile_confirm");
        final String cancel = getStringResourceByName("profile_cancel");    

        MainActivity._Instance.ActivityWillBeShown = true;
        MainActivity._Instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {                   
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity._Instance);
                alert.setCancelable(false);

                alert.setTitle(title);
               // alert.setMessage(""); // message

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity._Instance);
                final int maxLength = 12;                       

                input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter() {                     
                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
                         return "";
                        }                           
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }
                } , new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});

                //input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS); //turn off txt auto complete
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS); // type only text,numbers and some special char              

                alert.setView(input);
                //input.setText("Player");

                alert.setPositiveButton(createP, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  String value = input.getText().toString();
                  // Do something with value!   

                  if (value.isEmpty()){
                      value = "Player";
                  }

                  nativeName(value);                     

                  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);

                }

                });

                alert.setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
                  }
                });

                alert.show();                  
              };
        });
    }
```

And Whenever you need keyboard you just call this function. It works on all Android versions (4.x, 5.x, 6.0)